AWS S3 yandex, не удаляет файл deleteObject
Помогите пожалуйста, использую яндекс storage, библиотеку загрузил AWS S3 через архив. Создал файл даже без расширения, в настройках отключены версии и доступ Фулл_контроль на этот файл сделал. в Мониторинге видно что метод deleteObject вызывался.
Очевиднее всего что неправильный ключ объекта. Но куда проще файла "11" в корне бакета... версия PHP 8.2
require_once('aws-autoloader.php');
        
$bucket = 'bot';
$server_y = 'https://storage.yandexcloud.net/' . $bucket. '/' ;
$Key = '11';

$sharedConfig = [
'credentials' => [
'key'      => $GLOBALS['key_y'],
'secret'   => $GLOBALS['secret_y'],],
 'region'   => 'ru-central1',
  'endpoint' => $server_y,
  'version'  => 'latest',
];
$sdk = new Aws\Sdk($sharedConfig);
$s3Client = $sdk->createS3();
$s3Client->deleteObject([
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $Key,
]);

пробовал разные файлы
